# @types/styled-components returning type any instead of StyledComponent. Expected behavior?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, styled-components

If I use `@types/styled-components` version 4.4.1 or higher, all of my styled components' types change from `StyledComponent` to  `any`. Is this expected behavior?

I'm currently using `styled-components@4.4.1`, but I have the same issue using the latest version and type declarations.

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

const ErrorMessage = styled.label`
  color: red;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
`; // any
```

Comment: definitely not expected. `ErrorMessage` should be properly typed as TypeScript should be able to infer the typings as long as `@types/styled-components` is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd post my findings if anyone should stumble upon this with the same issue. One of my dependencies installed `hoist-non-react-statics@2` which causes errors for `@types/styled-components` v4.1.1 and higher.

Running `npm i --save-dev @types/hoist-non-react-statics@3` fixed it for me.